# Exception in using <#list> undefined variable does not generate pdf

Tags: java, exception, freemarker

I am trying to list all the credit terms using the following code, however, it produces this error: Exception: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException
Message: Expression supplier.vouchers is undefined on line 345, column 16.

```
<#list supplier.vouchers as voucher>
          <fo:table-cell padding-left="3px" column-width="200px" text-align="center" border="1px solid black">
            <fo:block>${voucher.creditTerm}</fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
          </#list>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable you reference is not defined. You have to check if it is defined or not:

```
<#if supplier?? && supplier.vouchers?? > 
    <#list supplier.vouchers as voucher>
        <fo:table-cell padding-left="3px" column-width="200px" text-align="center" border="1px solid black">
            <fo:block>${voucher.creditTerm}</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </#list>
</#if>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if it's not defined? What can I do to access the data?

Comment: You have to put your Java object you want to access through `supplier` it into the freemarker context, on the Java side, with the name "supplier".

Comment: I think I have done it already using this code:  <#list listIt as supplier> is this wrong? newbie here.

Comment: Ok, and what type is the "listIt" object? Does it have a `vouchers` field, accompanied with the necessary getter method `getVouchers()`? And is `listIt.getVouchers()` not null on Java side?